# Use Defined Windows User instead of NT AUTHORITY / IUSR

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, windows-authentication

I have an Asp.Net MVC 2 Web Application and an SQL Express service.
Is it possible to use a defined Windows user instead of the built-in IUSR to connect to the database.

If yes, please indicate the required settings

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to run all your DB requests as a specific user then modify your app pool to run as the desired user. See [Specify an Identity for an Application Pool](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771170%28v=ws.10%29.aspx). This is the correct way, you will find plenty of bad advice on this topic, like using [LogonUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378184%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). Don't do that.

If you want to connect to the DB as whichever the user that connected to your intranet site, then you need to use impersonation ( see [ASP.NET Impersonation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5.aspx)) and enable constrained delegation (see [Configuring Constrained Delegation for IIS](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc736864%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)).

Comment: Nice thats work, The application pool was my problem. Many thans.

Answer (score 0):

You might try the following connection string:

```
Data Source=.\SQLExpress;Initial Catalog=yourDataBase;Integrated Security=SSPI;
```

Also make sure that Windows Authentication is enabled for the SQL server.

Comment: I Already got that setting . But instead of Integrated Security=SSPI I got Integrated Securtity=true

Comment: @Jean-Francois, OK, so what gives?